# How to get date attribute in cart page using ubercart?

Tags: ubercart

I am Trying to develop an event based Drupal website using the [ubercart](https://www.drupal.org/project/ubercart) module.

I have to provide date and time field in product page, cart page and checkout page for users to book their tickets on specific time period.

I should also be able to limit the date and time based on booking count, similar to a movie ticket booking system.

Is there any possible module that provides this functionality?

FYI: I did try using [Agreservations](https://www.drupal.org/project/agreservations) module but it is not yielding my expectation.